# How to jumble up an array with n values in c++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to make a function that mixes up the values of a given ordered array, say from 0 to n. So this is my try:

```
void JumbleUp(int *sorted,int n){
int jumble[n];
bool mark[n];
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
    mark[i]=false;
int aux=0;
srand(time(NULL));
for(int i=0;i<n;i++){

    do {
        aux=(rand()%n);
        }while (mark[aux]);

    jumble[i]=sorted[aux];
    mark[aux]=true;
    }
```

The problem is that this function doesn't work for big integers because it takes a lot of time. So what can I do to improve my function or what others alternatives can I use to jumble up an array.

Comment: you should probably look at http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fisher%E2%80%93Yates_shuffle

Comment: Try moving `srand` outside of the function (generally you should only call it once).

Comment: Do you have access to a C++11 compiler?

Comment: @Cornstalks  How to know if I have a C++11 compiler? Sorry for being so naive but I'm just a begginer at computers. I use codeblocks 12.11, but I dont know about the compiler.

Comment: Instead of using `mark` to track which ones haven't been jumbled, you could try an in-place jumbling (copying from sorted to jumble first if necessary), with `for (i = 0; i < n - 1; ++i) std::swap(jumble[i], jumble[i + rand() % (n - i)]);`. That way, you don't spin in that do-while loop trying to find a still un-jumbled element: that gets increasingly unlikely and slow as the number of elements increases.

Comment: heh. I assume [`std::random_shuffle()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/random_shuffle) is out of the question if this is homework =P

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are overthinking it. First of all call `srand` only once when program starts. Then for algorithm, something like pseudocode

```
for index in 0..n-1
    index2 = random (0..n-1)
    swap (ar, index, index2)
```

I could be wrong here, but I think it's important to get `index2` in above range `0..n-1` and not for example `index..n-1`, so every piece has equal chance to end up in all locations. Alternative suggested in comment is this, which may also produce evenly distributed shuffle:

```
for index in 0..n-2
    index2 = random (index..n-1)
    swap (ar, index, index2)
```

Comment: I would change the second line to `index2 = random (index .. n-1)` This prevents you putting values back after they have randomized their position.

Comment: @LokiAstari I don't think that matters, actually, as long as value has exactly 1:n chance of ending up in it's original location. Statistics have never been very intuitive to me... In any case, doing it the way you suggest, the loop needs to go only from `0..n-2`, as last iteration would only swap last element with itself, so it is marginally more efficient.

Comment: Unfortunately Knuth disagrees with you.